# Turning formula into ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have this formula for counting matches in `Contents!$B$2` in `J4`.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(J4, 
"\w")),0,SUM(COUNTIF(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(J4,","),"
[\s]",""),REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(Contents!$B$2,","),"[\s]","")))))
```

The formula is in `K4` but ideally, I want it to work right down `J` returning values to the relevant adjacent `K`. I tried this but it didn't work. Just filled the cell the formula was in

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(J4:J, 
"\w")),0,SUM(COUNTIF(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(J4:J,","),"
[\s]",""),REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(Contents!$B$2,","),"[\s]","")))))
```

I know I can just fill down but the issue is users inserting rows.

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: Sure. Here it is:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12xATTwuc-e6kXn_OF2Uibg6EgtSGbInI6Q_-vueknXg/edit?usp=sharing. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(Contents!B1, ","))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1", 0), 2, 0), 0), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I'll try and dissect it.