# Turning formula into ArrayFormula Part2

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

Following on from this question
[Turning formula into ArrayFormula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193646/turning-formula-into-arrayformula)

I failed to make it clear that the value cells may also contain multiple values in CSV format. I tried adjusting it to:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A4:A), IFERROR(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(A4:A,","), 
 QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT($B$1, ","))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1", 0), 2, 0), 0), ))
```

But no luck. The test sheet is here. 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12xATTwuc-e6kXn_OF2Uibg6EgtSGbInI6Q_-vueknXg/edit#gid=0

My original formula is in `B4` which works but needs copying down which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: how many CSV values could be in A4?

Comment: Pretty much endless unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4:A, QUERY({QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(A4:A), "♠"&A4:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(A4:A, ","))), )), , 999^99)), , 999^99), "♠")), "♦")), "select Col1", 0),
 ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(A4:A), "♠"&A4:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(A4:A, ","))), ))
 , , 999^99)), , 999^99), "♠")), "♦")), "select Col2", 0), QUERY(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
 QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(A4:A),
 "♠"&A4:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(A4:A, ","))), )), , 999^99)), , 999^99), "♠")), "♦")),
 "select Col2", 0), QUERY(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1, ","))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1", 0), {1, 2}, 0)), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1", 0), 2, 0), 0), COUNTA(QUERY(TRIM(SPLIT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(LEN(A4:A),
 "♠"&A4:A&"♦"&TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(A4:A, ","))), )), , 999^99)), , 999^99), "♠")), "♦")),
 "select Col1", 0)), 1)}, "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1" ,0), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow. Now that's a formula! Thanks player0